# Can't figure out data binding in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently I started developing apps in Android studio via Kotlin, because Java seemed a bit harder. I built my first app and now, for the second, I wanna try out data binding. I follow a Udacity tutorial and there it says that I have to include `dataBinding{ enabled=True }` which I did.

The problem is that when I try to import `com.android.AppName.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`
the name is red, even though I declared the variable below, in the `onCreate`
Everything related to data binding is red pretty much.

I can't figure out what's the problem. Any suggestion would help. Thanks!

Comment: Show your code with problem part, please

Answer (score 0):

I actually know the answer to this.

You need to update your dependencies. You can check out the github project they recommend you download and you'll notice your dependencies are not appropriate for databinding. Can't remember exactly what it is but you need to either update a version on one of the dependencies or you need to add an entirely new dependency in.

Comment: I did the exact same tutorial a few weeks ago and wondered the same thing. No note about it or anything.

Comment: Actaully if this doesn't work, try this:apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use kapt if you're using it with kotlin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   ...
   dataBinding {
       enabled true
   }
}


dependencies {
   ...
   kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3'
}
```